# Vlookup In Excel not working all the time

Tags: vlookup

I am trying to use VLOOKUP from one database to another. It is for a quoting form. Sometimes the formula works and sometimes it doesnt.

Example below:
[image: vlookup]

Actual formula here

```
=IF(C9="",0,IF(VLOOKUP(C9,'tracy price list.xlsx'!Database,1)=C9,VLOOKUP(C9,'tracy price list.xlsx'!Database,2),FALSE))
```

Why does it work sometimes and sometimes it doesnt????
Thanks
Tracy

Answer (score 0):

Could you further elaborate on your concern? What output is it returning when you mean "it's not returning"?

I tried reviewing the provided formula, and somehow the logic seems messed up. You may try the following revised one, which first checks if C9 is blank. If so, return 0. Otherwise, perform the VLOOKUP() function to get the value from the price list corresponding to the value of C9.

```
=IF(C9="",0,VLOOKUP(C9,'tracy price list.xlsx'!Database,2,0))
```

If it returns an error, it means the value of C9 is nowhere to be found in the database.